# Is it possible to use Javascript to change values of all numbers on a page?

Tags: javascript

I am aware you can use javascript to change text by supplying the Element ID like so:

```
<p id="textelement">I am a text element</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("textelement").innerHTML = "New text inside the text element!";
</script>
```

I have a HTML document which contains 100's of numbers, the numbers all have the same type tag:

```
<p type="number">1</p>
<p type="number">2</p>
<p type="number">3</p>
<p type="number">4</p>
<p type="number">5</p>
```

I would like to be able to multiple the numbers by a value supplied in JavaScript, so that when i change the value, all numbers on the page are multiplied by this value, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you can select elements by all kinds of approaches, not just by their id. Learn about [DOM selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give each one a class tag. Then, use `document.getElementsByClassName` inside of a `for` statement and find each one with an index.

```js
var multiplyBy = 4;
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('number');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].innerHTML *= multiplyBy;
}
```

```html
<p class='number'>1</p>
<p class='number'>2</p>
<p class='number'>3</p>
<p class='number'>4</p>
<p class='number'>5</p>
<p class='number'>6</p>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.number');` would work the same as `document.querySelectorAll('[type=number]');` so no need for a class

Comment: @mplungjan Amazing. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

With a few lines of Vanilla JS (ES6)

```js
let elems = [...document.querySelectorAll('[type=number]')];
let mult = 5;
elems.map( elem => { // a .forEach suits better ;)
  elem.innerHTML = parseInt(elem.innerHTML) * mult;
});
```

```html
<p type="number">1</p>
<p type="number">2</p>
<p type="number">3</p>
<p type="number">4</p>
<p type="number">5</p>
```

Comment: But why map. Why not forEach? You do not need nor use the returned array from the map

Comment: you're right, if you want to know why : ..... i'm lazy : map (3 char) forEach (7 letters and one uppercase ) ^^

Comment: `let mult = 5; [...document.querySelectorAll('[type=number]')].forEach(el => el.textContent*=mult);`

Comment: that's not the same, with your code you're not able to do a parseInt()

Comment: there is no need for a parseInt when you multiply. My code works too. Try it. you only need to cast when you add. And if you want to save typing use `+elem.textContent` if you must convert

Answer (score 0):

Since this is customdata you could use could use `data-` attributes and get the `p` elements you want using `querySelectorAll`  Below is a simple example using `promises`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p[data-type="number"]').forEach((v,k) => {
let oldValue = parseInt(v.textContent);
let prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let pValue = oldValue + parseInt(10*Math.random());
    resolve(pValue);
});
prom.then((response) => {
  v.innerHTML = response;
  console.info('paragraph '+k+' changed from '+oldValue+' to '+response);
});
});
```

```html
<p>Paragraph one</p>
<p>Paragraph two</p>
<p>Paragraph three</p>
<p data-type="number">1</p>
<p data-type="number">2</p>
<p data-type="number">3</p>
<p data-type="number">4</p>
<p data-type="number">5</p>
```